# ros-sharp Service call sample

Tags: ros

I created sample ros service to add 2 numbers. I put the code on git:

https://github.com/Thazz/ros_service_example

I can test service with:

rosservice call /add_numbers [1,2]

and get response "sum: 3.0" what is OK,

But don't know how to do the same call with ros-sharp over rosbridge.

I try the only sample from: https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp/blob/master/Libraries/RosBridgeClientTest/RosSocketConsoleExample.cs
and it work OK but only for **GetParamRequest**

```
// Service Call:
rosSocket.CallService<rosapi.GetParamRequest, rosapi.GetParamResponse>("/rosapi/get_param", ServiceCallHandler, new rosapi.GetParamRequest("/rosdistro", "default"));
```

How to change this line to call my add_numbers???

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to generate the C# service files. You can do this by using the console tool provided by *ROS#*:

```
RosMsgGen.exe -s SPECIFIC_PATH\ros_service_example-master\srv --recursive -n ros_service_example
```

After generation, *AddNumbersRequest* will look like this:

```
/* 
 * This message is auto generated by ROS#. Please DO NOT modify.
 * Note:
 * - Comments from the original code will be written in their own line 
 * - Variable sized arrays will be initialized to array of size 0 
 * Please report any issues at 
 * <https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp> 
 */

using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace RosSharp.RosBridgeClient.MessageTypes.RosServiceExample
{
    public class AddNumbersRequest : Message
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public const string RosMessageName = "ros_service_example/AddNumbers";

        public double[] numbers;

        public AddNumbersRequest()
        {
            this.numbers = new double[0];
        }

        public AddNumbersRequest(double[] numbers)
        {
            this.numbers = numbers;
        }
    }
}
```

With this class (and the also generated *AddNumbersResponse*), you are able to call the service:

```
//Use namespace
using RosSharp.RosBridgeClient.MessageTypes.RosServiceExample;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...

    //Prepare service request
    AddNumbersRequest request = new AddNumbersRequest(new double[] { 1, 2 });
    //Call service request
    rosSocket.CallService<AddNumbersRequest, AddNumbersResponse>("/add_numbers", ServiceCallHandler, request);

    ...
}

//Handler
private static void ServiceCallHandler(AddNumbersResponse message)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + message.sum);
}
```